# Rdlc - Page Header creates GAP if content is hidden, when exported to pdf

Tags: .net, winforms, reporting, rdlc

I have designed a rdlc report in winform. In page Header Some content is to be present in First Page only, So i put them in Rectangle as :

[image: Rdlc Report]

When Rectangle is hidden on next pages, its creating a Gap (based on rectangle height) *When exported to pdf*. I have set Rectangle visibility as

> =Globals!PageNumber >1

and then reports looks like on next pages as :

[image: Gap of 2-3 lines in Page Header]

Since Data 1 and data 2 is of 2-3 Lines, So A gap of 2-3 lines is created in Page Header, ***When exported to pdf***.

**How to remove the Gap or Set Dynamic Height of Page Header ?**

Answer (score 1):

Open the report in designer:

- Right-click on the report → Insert → Page Header.
- In the Page header, put 3 `TextBox` as header texts.
- For the second one, Right-click → TextBox Properties → Visibility → Select radio button *Show or hide based on an expression* → Click on <kbd>f<sub>x</sub></kbd> in front of TextBox → enter the following value for the hidden: `= Globals!PageNumber > 1`
- In the body,put the consents which you are going to have all pages.

Note: Whatever you put in page header, will show in all pages. But you can control its appearance using an expression. The expression sets the hidden property to true or false. Also keep in mind, in the content part out side of the table, will not repeat on pages. and will not occupy space after the first page. You also always can have something at the first page by inserting an unbound row as first row of the table.

**Design View**

[image]

**Page 1**

[image]

**Page 2**

[image]

Comment: Edited the answer to show how you can handle the situation which are facing with.

Comment: In Real Scenario, there are about 15 to 20 Textboxes that are in _Yellow Rectangle_ , that have to be visible ONLY on First page and in place of _Data 3_   there are 10 Textboxes that Must be shown in header of each page...

Comment: Select them all in designer, press `f4` to show *Properties* window, then set `= Globals!PageNumber > 1` to `Hidden` property of all of them.

Comment: Its Creating a gap of 2 lines between table and Header 3. Have you tried hiding header1 and header2 both ?

Comment: I tried hiding 2 and 3 and got expected result, without any gap.

Comment: I have edited the post, gap is coming while exported to pdf.... Pls try..

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look at the issue for export to pdf, but in report viewer, I can confirm there is no gap and it works properly.

Comment: OK, I can confirm Report Viewer shows properly, but exported pdf has gaps.

Comment: But the initial version of the question didn't contain export to pdf! It makes my answer nonsense.